# Why mysql return one row?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use count() function MySQL return one row. I need to use count function for pagination system, I don't have a better idea. 
My SQL is:

```
SELECT *, count(id_question) AS num FROM `questions` LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean... What would you like your query to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use any [aggregate function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp), without the `group by` clause you see only one result.

Answer (score 1):

The COUNT() is an aggregate function and so will group all the rows together. If you need the count of all rows just count the number of rows returned in whatever language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not allow to aggregate over the whole table and return all rows at the same time.

You have to use two queries, one for the total number of rows (count) and one for the rows themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ...

```
SELECT *, count(*) AS num FROM `questions` LIMIT 0, 10
```

or simply using mysql_num_rows() to get the count?

Answer (score 0):

Since count is an aggregate function, it will by design only return one row. You would have two use two queries, one for the select and one for the count.
Alternatively you could do a nested select:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count(id_question) from 'questions') AS num FROM `questions` LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: I believe this is a relatively expensive operation, as it will perform the sub query for each row. Better to INNER JOIN the sub query if I'm correct, like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076120/why-mysql-return-one-row/7076297#7076297

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_num_rows($queryHandle)` on your normal results query. An example:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `questions` LIMIT 0, 10';
$queryHandle = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($queryHandle);
$firstRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM `questions` a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT count(`id_question`) as `num`
  FROM `questions`
) b
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Each row will now have the total row count of the table as a column called `num`.